# impala Jdbc driver with Gradle dependancy

Tags: jdbc, impala

I can be able connect with Impala using JDBC driver and following jars in my class path.

```
hive_metastore.jar
hive_Service.jar
impalaJDBC3.jar
libfb303-0.9.0.jar
libthrift-0.9.0.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
ql.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
TCLIDerviceClient.jar
```

We are using gradle dependency tool,  I tried to find out to download dependency for above jars. But I couldn't able to find dependency for "impalaJDBC3.jar
" . 
Can anyone tell me how should I add these jars into gradle build tool(build.gradle file).

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

These are the 2 steps you will need.  Reference the picture also.

> 1. In your project create a folder with the JARs.  Like "lib"
> 2. Build.gradle: under dependencies add -> "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])"

[image]